# VLOOKUP in MSAccess

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to do something similar to a Vlookup on Access to a table, however if I use set and where it ends up duplicating some lines of the report, here's a sample of what I want if it was an excel formula (works like a charm on Excel)

```
=IF(G1520="RU",(IF([@PROCV]="Document not found","Unapplied",(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AB:AB,H:K,4,FALSE),K:K)))),"N/A")
```

Comment: MS Access offers [DLookup](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) and [IIf()](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) Would those be suitable?

Comment: I think the actual table structure and what’s your goal would be much better than an Excel formula. Would you please add that to the question (that would also be more compliant to how a question would better be posted)? Thanks.

Comment: Basically what I have is two tables: First I use the Dossier number to find the invoice number and add it to the first table. Then I use this Invoice number to find the Due date of said invoice.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. Basically what I wanted was an UPDATE function using the Where statement so it looked like this:

```
UPDATE [Insight Final Table], INVANALYS SET [Insight Final Table].Invoice = [INVANALYS].[INVOICENO]
```

WHERE (([Insight Final Table].[Dossier]=[INVANALYS].[DOSSIER]));

Thanks everyone for the answer!